# How can you have standard enthalpy of formation of water at 298 K?

Tags: thermodynamics

Firstly, I want to clarify in advance that im not good at this subject.
Secondly, when i go through my chem book to search for thermodynamic data of water at 298 kelvin. I am able to find the standard enthalpy of formation of water in its gaseous state as well as solid state. How can you have water in gaseous/solid form at 298 kelvin? Water only exists in its liquid form at 298 kelvin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Water can be gaseous at 298 kelvin, if the pressure is low enough (< 3167 Pa).

Comment: @Maurice You mean vapor partial pressure, as water evaporates even at 100 kPa.

Comment: But as far as I know, these reactions are preceded under standard state conditions, thus room temperature and 1 atm. So pressure cannot be high enough.

Comment: These reactions are wrapped by formal operations leading from and to standard conditions. This can be done for enthalpy cases by formal heating or cooling of reagents and products. By the Hess law, the enthalpy change does not depend on the path.// E.g. reaction enthalpy at 25°C = enthalpy of reagent heating 25to90°C, + reaction enth. at 90°C + enthalpy of product cooling 90to25 °C.

Answer (score 3):

Water vapor at 25 C and 1 atm is a hypothetical ideal gas state.  You can get the enthalpy of this state by starting with liquid water at 25 C and 1 atm, then dropping the pressure of the liquid to the equilibrium vapor pressure at 25 C, then adding the heat of vaporization at 25 C; for an ideal gas state, going from water vapor at the equilibrium vapor pressure at 25 C to the hypothetical ideal gas sate of 25 C and 1 atm requires no enthalpy change.